# Google Sheets - Formula to split words by uppercase and or number?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I just need to remove each players position off their name ( the last 1 or 2 chars),

[image: player 1st]

So it would be "2B" for Ketel Marte  and "CF" for Carroll
The function will go through an entire column and then return **just** the player name in a different cell/column.
I just couldn't figure out the formula for this but I know  =Left(Length)) and maybe replaceregex might be involved

i tried =Left(Length))   and REPLACEREGEX   but i don't want to have to do each name separately

Comment: Hi. You've tagged your question with `excel` as well as `google-sheets`. Would you please choose one or the other; you can't have both.

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"(.*?)\d?[A-Z]+$")))
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful thankyou this did the entire row ... I'm just still trying to learn and get used to all the sintax

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TOCOL(A2:A,1),"[A-Z\d]+$",""))
```